# set image from URL inside movable relative layout

Tags: android

I have a Movable Relative Layout which can be re positioned anywhere in the screen.
I referred to this link for making my relative layout movable.

https://github.com/bara96/MovableFloatingActionButton

I have one imageview, textview and a recyclerview in it.
Now, When I set image in my imageview using URL which comes from API it doesn't works as expected.
If I set imageview's background in xml file and not in my Activity then it works fine.

Any leads are welcomed.

layout of MovableRelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MovableRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMovFloatingButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
    android:visibility="gone">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFloatingButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/imgFloatingButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgFloatingButton"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_1sdp"
        tools:itemCount="1"
        tools:listitem="@layout/floating_image_item" />

</MovableRelativeLayout>
```

I set image in imageview like this

```
Glide.with(context)
                                .load(item.getBusiness_logo())
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                                .circleCrop()
                                .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                                .into(imgFloatingButton);
```

**Problem I faced and why I faced**

imageview(imgFloatingButton) click listener was creating a problem for me.
My requirement made me do something like this i.e., on click of imgFloatingButton, a small popup will open up. So, I did that like this.

```
imgFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(this)
```

So, when I was trying to drag the movable relative layout it was not doing so.

Comment: Can you better explain what do you mean with 'doesn't works as expected'?

Comment: @Jameido I cannot reposition it. It doesn't takes touch event when I dynamically set image in imageview using API URL.

Comment: With the given info it's not possibile to find a solution, I still cannot completely understand the situation and the whole problem

Comment: http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/simple-moving-object-with-touch-events.html?m=1.  I wanted to achieve something like this which is happening also but when I set image using Glide it is not working. Hope now you understand what J am trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your imageview inside relative layout has wrap_content size and when you set image ,it take whole view's width and height and your relative layout can not get touch event on itself. first set small width and height to your imageview then test it. if problem solved then you need give imageview's touch event to your relative layout.

Comment: I have kept width and height of inageview to 35 sdp both